# RawPrinter Helper: Printer not printing Tamil characters

Tags: c#, thermal-printer

Trying to print tamil characters in thermal printer. and getting '????' or any other garbage character.
code I am using is as follows.

```
         Print(eInit + 'நன்றி');

         public void Print(string Line)
         {
             prn.SendStringToPrinter(PrinterName, Line);
         }

         public bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
         {
             bool functionReturnValue = false;
             if (PrinterOpen)
             {
                 IntPtr pBytes = default(IntPtr);
                 Int32 dwCount = default(Int32);
                 Int32 dwWritten = 0;
                 dwCount = szString.Length;
                 pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
                 functionReturnValue = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, ref dwWritten);
                 Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
             }
             else
             {
                 functionReturnValue = false;
             }
             return functionReturnValue;
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw printer helper class wont print tamil characters through sensstringtoprinter() class.
Design a crystal report select your field and set font as any tamil font(eg. bamini font) and call this report to print from your application on button click event.

Comment: it will, just convert you string to byte array with UTF-8 Encoding then pass your byte array to memory stream

Answer (score 0):

i know this is old but for the reference of others who will encounter this issue let me  post may solution.

```
public static bool SendStringToPrinterUTF8(string szPrinterName, string szString)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(szString);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray); 
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[stream.Length];
            IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
            int nLength;

            nLength = Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length);
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
            pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
            return true;

        }


public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
        {
            Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

            di.pDocName = "Printing UCC Labels";
            di.pDataType = "RAW";

            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write your bytes.
                        bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
            // about why not.
            if (bSuccess == false)
            {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return bSuccess;
        }
```